# What is the graphical formula when nitrobenzene is added to HCL and tin?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, amines

[image]
On the image i want to work out the structure of compound Q. I know that it is a reduction reaction. However why is it that the answer to this question is not C6H5NH2, but is actually (C6H5NH3)+Cl-

Comment: You are on the right track! The reduction product of nitrobenzene is indeed aniline. But there's $\ce{HCl}$ on top of the arrow and aniline is a base. Protonation gives $\ce{PhNH3+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ is around too.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Okay. So am I right in saying that if I have the salt that you specified and I add NaOH, will I get C6H5NH2 ? Also, what is the easiest way to recognize a base such as this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Addition of $\ce{NaOH}$ will release the aniline. One has to keep in mind that the reducing agent is actually $\ce{Sn^{2+}}$, which is formed by the reaction of the cheap tin metal with hydrochloric acid. Workup with   $\ce{NaOH}$ is a standard step for this kind of reduction. As far as the base is concerned: proton goes where lone pair waits. Looking for amines helps :)